# there are two way to test View.onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state), one works the other crashes

Tags: java, android, parcel

onRestoreInstanceState can be tested by changing screen orientation, and by changing the emulator settings devtools/Development Settings/ max app process - with max set to one.
onRestoreInstanceState works with the screen orientation but crashes with max app process set to 1 and restarting the app.  I used Debug.waitForDebugger(); to connect the debugger for the max app process set to 1.

In the view a parsable is saved restored recurivly:

restoring:

```
MyClass(Parcel in) {   

            boolean boolValues[] = new boolean[2];

            in.readBooleanArray(boolValues);
            if (boolValues[1])
            {

               next = in.readParcelable(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
            }
            //
            //recurse here 
        }
```

saving:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean boolValues[] = new boolean[2];
    boolValues[0] = aValue;
    boolValues[1] = next != null;
    out.writeBooleanArray(boolValues);


    if (boolValues[1])
    {
        out.writeParcelable(next,flags);
    }

}
```